# Tilt Control Similar to Temple run

Tags: unity-game-engine, accelerometer, tilt

I want to create tilt effect just like temple run.I have a character controller(player) in the game that is moving on its forward by controller.Move(transform.forward) after which I am apply tilt to it to lean it left and right .Previously for the tilt I tried modifying the player position by using transform.translate /tranform.position directly through the accelerometer readings like this :

```
mytransform.translate(acceleration.x*Time.delaTime*5.0f);
```

but that had a problem that when I shake the device my camera starts to jerk and the player also then I used the following code to create tilt on positive Z axis

```
Vector3 dir = new Vector3(accel.x*8f, 0,0);
    if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1) 
{
    dir.Normalize();

}
dir.x = Mathf.Round(dir.x * 10f) / 10f;

//mytemp is used for temp storage of player position added with the acceleration 
mytemp = mytransform.position+(mytransform.right*dir.x*Time.deltaTime*5.0f);

Vector3 diffVec=Vector3.zero;
///position of the element on which the player is colliding;
Vector3 col_pos=Collidingelement.transform.position;
Vector3 unitvec=new Vector3(1,0,0);
//removing x and z of the collider
diffVec= Vector3.Scale(col_pos,unitvec);
//nullify the y,z of the updated mytransform position so that the distance is only measured on X
Vector3 ppos = Vector3.Scale(mytemp,unitvec);
//calculate the distance between player & colliding element
 disti=Vector3.Distance( ppos,diffVec);
disti=Mathf.Clamp(disti,-1.5f,1.5f);
disti = Mathf.Round(disti * 10f) / 10f;
//update the player position and apply tilt to it if the distance is less than 1.5f
if(disti<=1.50f)
{
mytransform.position=mytemp;

}
```

now this has a problem that if lets say I have a value of 0.1 in the acceleration its keep on update my temp and if the distance is less my player will start leaning towards a side though I held my device on same position and acceleration value was always 0.1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just calculate delta acceleration.

```
bool isMoved = false;
Vector2 lastAccel = Vector2.Zero;
Vector2 margin = new Vector2(0.05f, 0.05f);  //not processing if its in margin.
Vector2 deltaAccel = currAccel - lastAccel ;

if(deltaAccel.x < margin.x)
{
   //don't process
   isMove = false;
}
else
{
   isMove = true;
   lastAccel = currAccel;
}

if(isMove)
{
//Process with deltaAccel here
}
```